# React-Bootstrap NavItem not Firing onClick Handler

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to call a click event handler when I click on a NavItem using React-Bootstrap.

I have the following code:

```
<Navbar fluid inverse>
            <Navbar.Header>
                <Navbar.Brand>
                    {first} {last}
                </Navbar.Brand>
                <Navbar.Toggle/>
            </Navbar.Header>
            <Navbar.Collapse>
            <Nav>
                {navItems.map(item => {
                    return(
                        <NavItem                           
                        key={item[1]}
                        eventKey={item[1]}
                        onClick={()=> this.handleClick}
                        >
                            {item[0]}
                        </NavItem>
                    );
                })}                  
            </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>
```

With this as my click handler:

```
handleClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(event);
}
```

What's goofy, is that this doesn't work, however, when I have the onClick to equal:

```
<NavItem                           
  key={item[1]}
  eventKey={item[1]}
  onClick={()=> console.log("Hello")}
  >
  {item[0]}
 </NavItem>
```

It works fine, it is only when I add the click handler... any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `onClick={()=> this.handleClick() }`. In your case you have `this.handleClick` inside the `() => ()` function. So `onClick` is executing `() => ()`, but in the body of this function `this.handleClick` is just the function object, it is not getting executed as you didn't invoke it with `()`.

I'd suggest to do `onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}` for [performance](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) reason.

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that **you are not calling the function** you are returning it.
replace this line:

```
onClick={()=> this.handleClick}
```

with:

```
onClick={()=> this.handleClick()}
```

also If you want to access event in your function you should pass it to your function:

```
onClick={e => this.handleClick(e)}
```

---

### A little more explanation

in arrow functions this:

```
() => this.someFunction
```

translates to:

```
var that = this
function() {
  return that.someFunction
}
```

Comment: Awesome! This worked. Thanks for the extra explanation

Comment: @bflynnigan so why didn't you mark it as correct answer? :D

Comment: I wanted to, but I could only mark one answer as the right answer, and the guy who posted before you posted the right answer as well :(